# Query related to Bluemix Secure Gateway Client on DataPower

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway, apiconnect

Our customer is planning for APIC on Bluemix cloud to On-premise connectivity for IIB APIs.
For secure connection we are planning to use Secure gateway service on Bluemix and creating secure gateway client on customer existing DataPower .

At present there is an internet connectivity via eth0 of DataPower at customer datacenter where a service is running on 443.
We want to seggregate traffic comming from Bluemix and the existing non-bluemix traffic.
So We are planning to create a new eth1 dedicated for Bluemix calls, that will also talk to internet on port 443 and 9000 (as required by secure gateway service) .

How do we make sure Bluemix traffic cames to Gateway via Eth1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Secure Gateway Client initiates the connection to the SG Servers in Bluemix with the combination of requests across 443 and 9000.  Once that connection has been initiated, it will remain open and all traffic from Secure Gateway will travel across it.